# How far is a espresso brew coffee nitrogen molecules to those able to be absorbed by plants?

Tags: soil, fertilizer, nutrients

I live in a small apartment with 3 small balconies, all of them full of plants.  Most of the plants have big roots and are in too small pots, just because I don't have enough space or I have too many plants, or both.

I want my plants to grow big and healthy, so once a year I try to make some space for new soil, taking out some roots with my hands. However, I feel it is useful to give them some extra nutrients in the water to try to compensate the lack of soil. But I would love not to use fertilizers.

I am adding remains of (great specialty) espresso coffee in hopes of helping the plant grow, but I really don't know if those molecules can be absorbed or how long it spends in the soil before my plants drink it.

I found that these are the most common molecules in a brewed coffee: Caffeine, Tannin, Thiamin, Xanthine, Spermidine, Guaiacol, Citric acid, Chlorogenic acid, Acetaldehyde, Spermine, Putrescine, Scopoletin. All of them are basically C or H or N or O mixed molecules, so I know I will need at least some extra Phosphorous and Potassium.

My expectations: Making a espresso extracts better the nutrients from the coffee grounds and therefore there shouldn't be much process left to be ready to be absorbed.

Thank you

Comment: Look up coffee grounds composting. The growth will be slowed down otherwise.